# How to change shade of color dynamically android?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, palette

I'm using the Palette class to programmatically get the most dominant color from an image which I then want to use for my status bar and toolbar. According to the material design guidelines, the status bar color should be two shades darker than the toolbar color.

```
  Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) ((ImageView)mImageView).getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    if (bitmap != null) {
        palette = Palette.generate(bitmap);
        vibrantSwatch = palette.getVibrantSwatch();
        darkVibrantSwatch = palette.getDarkVibrantSwatch();
    }
```

For the darker color I'm using the darkVibrantSwatch and for the lighter color, I'm using the vibrantSwatch. But in most of the cases, these turn out to be very different from each other and hence essentially becoming unusable. Is there any workaround for this?
Maybe if its possible to get just one color, say darkVibrantSwatch, and then programmatically generate a color which is two shades lighter?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about getting exactly 2 shades lighter but you can play around with the SHADE_FACTOR and see if you can achieve what you want.

```
  private int getDarkerShade(int color) {
        return Color.rgb((int)(SHADE_FACTOR * Color.red(color)),
                (int)(SHADE_FACTOR * Color.green(color)),
                (int)(SHADE_FACTOR * Color.blue(color)));
    }
```

Code snippet taken from [here](https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/amulyakhare/textdrawable/TextDrawable.java#L69)

Answer (score 1):

An approach that works well is to modify the brightness value in the color's HSV representation:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
public static int modifyBrightness(int color, float factor) {
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
    hsv[2] *= factor;
    return Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
}
```

To get a suitably darker color for the status bar, use a factor of 0.8:

```
int darkerColor = modifyBrightness(color, 0.8);
```